# How to change which modules are auto-applied in Darktable?

Tags: darktable

When I open a raw file in Darktable sharpening and a base curve are automatically applied. How do I alter this? I would like to add lens correction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Automatic presets would do that, see the section ["Module presets"](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/darkroom/interacting-with-modules/presets/) in Darktable's user manual.  Note that you need Darktable version > 1.4 for this to work sensibly with lens correction.  In earlier versions the lens correction did not adapt correctly to the image parameters.

Relevant section from the manual:

> A module has an expander bar [image: expander bar screenshot for the Sharpen module]. Clicking on the name of the module
> expands the module's GUI with all parameters.
>
> In its default setting darktable will only expand one GUI at a time.
> If you click the expander bar of another module, the previous GUI gets
> collapsed. If you want to see more than one GUI expanded, you may
> expand further modules with shift-click  – all previously expanded
> GUIs remain opened. The expander bar behavior on click and
> shift-click, respectively, is controlled by a preference setting in
> gui options (see Section 8.1, “GUI options”).
>
> Expanding a module does not activate it. You need to click the [image: screenshot of the on/off icon from the expander bar] icon
> to turn a module on or off.
>
> Icon [image: hamburger menu from the expander bar] accesses the module's available presets or creates a new preset
> from your current settings (see Section 3.2.3, “Module presets”).

Comment: Also relevant is the [presets section](http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch06s04.html.php) of the manual.

Comment: Thanks, I'd mod you up twice for the version note if I could.

Comment: You always were a nice boy jamie :)

Comment: Updated link to [presets section](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/presets.html) linked by @LarsKotthoff in a previous comment.